# How can we force MacOS to forget that a specific file was downloaded from the web?

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

MacOS remember that things were downloaded. MacOS refuse to open or execute script downloaded and prompt the famous message:

> cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

Can I make MacOS forget this file was downloaded?

I know I can do a right-click -> open.  But I want to avoid the additional hassle for specific files. The protection is particularly annoying for bash script you may want to open in a text editor multiple time. I'm well aware of the risk of exectuting a downloaded script.

I also know I can remove the protection altogether, but I don't want that.

In the info of the files, you have the information but it's not editable:

[image]

Comment: Simple Gatekeeper bypass is right click>Open for first run. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Tetsujin The question does say they know they can do that, although it is lacking in detail about why that's not a sufficient solution.

Comment: @DavidZ I think the gist is, the OP wants to avoid the additional hassle for specific files, while not having to turn off protection for every file.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can delete the download source by running

```
xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms FILENAME
```

To also remove the quarantine flag use

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine FILENAME
```

PS: If `FILENAME` is an application (ends in `.app`), add `-r` to have the attributes removed from all files within the application.

Comment: Add "-r" if you need to remove the attribute from an application, folder, or bundle

Answer (score 1):

To create an app that can do this from the GUI, launch Automator.
Select New -> Application

In the Actions Library, go to Utilities and select "Run Shell Script"
In the Pass Input drop-down menu, select Select "As arguments"
[image: image of Run Shell Script]

Where it says `echo "$f"`, replace it with

  `xattr -d -r com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms $f
  xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine $f`

So the content of the shell script is 
`for f in "$@"
do
  xattr -d -r com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms $f
  xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine $f
done`

Save the app as "DeQuarantine.app" in a location you find convenient for Drag-and-drop (I put it on the Desktop).

Then, when you have downloaded files you want to remove the warnings from, drop them on this app.